# Programmatically installing font in Windows

Tags: fonts, installation

What's the trick to make a font file copied to the fonts directory and then added using AddFontResource available after a reboot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183326(VS.85).aspx) page has this to say:

> This function installs the font only
>   for the current session. When the
>   system restarts, the font will not be
>   present. To have the font installed
>   even after restarting the system, the
>   font must be listed in the registry.

I believe the key you need is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`

Comment: I must have been blind yeasterday - because I looked for that key and couldn't find it on my machine. Now I see it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue for the past few days and each solution I found was producing different problems.

I managed to come up with a working code with my colleague and I thought I'd share it for everyone. The code can be found in the following pastebin link:

[Installing a font programatically in C#](http://pastebin.com/C99TmXBn)

Comment: I was able to install fonts completely just by copying into the Windows Font directory. Why does your solution also call AddFontResource and manually add to the registry? By copying to Windows Font dir, I observed a registry entry being created for me, and the file accessible (after reboot) to MS Word (eg).

Comment: Back when I did this copying to the windows directory it did not add an entry to the registry - hence it was lost upon reboot. Maybe the functionality has changed over the months or I overlooked something. Either way, thanks for the information.